# how to display data from api by id in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this simple react native demo and i want to display data by specific id no all the data 
how can i do this ??

```
      componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('http://209.97.188.74/api/scategories')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.data,
        }, function(){
            });
          })
         }
      render(){
          return(
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.id}, {item.name}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: what is `responseJson.data`?

Comment: Flatlist accepts array into the data property.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `fetch()` inside of a `setTimeout()`

Like this:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  fetch('http://209.97.188.74/api/scategories')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson.data,
      });
    });
}, 100);
```